# Create Custom XSLT Functions using .NET XSLT Processor

Tags: .net, xml, function, xslt

It is possible to create custom functions using .NET 4.5 XSLT processor ?

All I could do is to create templates and call them by sending parameters.

There is a work-around or something ? or should I simple go to 2.0 ?

Something like this:

```
<xsl:function name="name">
... my function
</xsl:function>
```

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean scripts (vb, etc) inside the xslt? or do you mean external functions on objects that you pass in? both are possible

Comment: Hi Marc, I mean like xslt functions, I wanted to create my own function, now I'm using templates, but I wonder if .NET XSLT would work with these functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xsl:function` is a xsl 2.0 feature. The inbuilt .NET xsl processing is *not* 2.0 (it is W3C XSL Transformations (XSLT) Version 1.0 Recommendation).

You can use script blocks (via [`XsltSettings.EnableScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltsettings.enablescript(v=vs.110).aspx)), and you can use methods exposed on external objects (via [`XsltArgumentList.AddExtensionObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.addextensionobject(v=vs.110).aspx)). Or you can use a different (2.0) xslt processor; maybe [Saxon](http://www.saxonica.com/products/products.xml).

Comment: Nice! I think I will stick with .NET for now.